# Registry Update via Batch File Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, registry, history

So I have created a batch file that is to check certain registry settings for Internet Explorer and set them accordingly.  Web history is the primary target.  The dilemma is that I can get the batch file to update the proper keys but when I reopen IE it is still set to 20 days to remember history rather than what the registry is set to after the update.  I noticed that if I use regedit to manually update the keys and check in IE afterwards, IE is set the right way.  So I know the keys I am updating are the right ones.

To further complicate this I set the keys using regedit to 120 days remembrance.  I then ran my batch file to set them to 90 days.  I used regedit to verify the keys had been changed to 90 days successfully.  However, when I open IE to check that is is set to 90 as the keys are, guess what?  It is set to 20 days remembrance.  So, it is like it is resetting to defaults when I use the batch file.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run your batch file, reboot and check?  The settings may not 'take' till a log off or restart.

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well although typically a reboot is not required.  I did, however, just see that the HKCU item is being set back to 20 after I open IE post running the script.

Comment: So I am thinking that there is something in IE causing it set itself back to defaults once opened.

Comment: Was IE running when your batch was launched?

Comment: No.  I made sure the process was not running before updating.  I am having this issue on two different machines on two different networks.  So it has to be something I am missing setting wise.

Comment: Can you post the Key path and batch script for us to look at?

Comment: REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Url History" /v DaysToKeep /d 90 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Url History" /v DaysToKeep /d 90 /f
echo Registry settings updated.

Comment: Sorry.  Not sure how to post it nice and pretty.  New user to this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came that MS has a patch in place for IE that does not allow this type of 'backdoor' method.  GPO or Internet Options in IE are the only ways to officially implement these settings.  That is why the settings were changing back once IE was opened after I ran my script successfully.